# How to loop over snapshot dependencies parameters using teamcity REST API

Tags: teamcity

In my CentOS 7 setup , Top level job 'Build A' has snapshot dependencies on other jobs 'Build B' and 'Build C'.

I am currently referring to parameters from those dependent Build B and Build C  using '%dep.Build_B.param%' and '%dep.Build_C.param%' hardcoded in build step in top-level 'Build-A' job.

However list of dependent  jobs may change forcing me to change hardcoded dependent job/build name params.

Is there any Teamcity REST API where i can get list of Jobs that are dependent on current Job?
So that i can loop over their build ids and construct '%dep' param name dynamically.

Answer was not found by googling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find dependencies for your Build Configuration

You could try request the Build Configuration and provide required fields as a query parameters.

In terms of TeamCity Rest API the BuildConfiguration is named "BuildType"

Example:

```
GET /app/rest/buildTypes/{BUILD_CONFIGURATION_ID}?fields=artifact-dependencies,snapshot-dependencies
```

BuildType fields documented:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/buildtype.html#Properties

BuildType locator documented:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/buildtypelocator.html
(locator in example is `{BUILD_CONFIGURATION_ID}`)